# How to do feature engineering of real time data?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression, feature-extraction, data-science

I have made a good linear regression model with following step:

1. Data Integration
2. Data normalization/scaling(data preprocessing & feature engineering)
3. Model Building(using linear regression with SGD using cross validation)
4. Testing

My question is if we use this model in production environment then how can we do feature engineering of real time data because this **model is built with feature normalization and scaling** so how real time data can be normalized and scaled to get a good prediction? We don't need explicit feature engineering for cross validation and testing step because this can be done in data preprocessing step before building a model. What about **real time data feature engineering**?

Comment: Can you explain what you use for normalization and scaling? Also, If you have trained and built your model off-line, which means, you store it and want to use it in a real-time situation then what you have in your hands is the same process (more or less) where you have to test your model the usual way with a train-test split (thus, pre-process and normalize the test data the same way). Take a look at [this](http://sentic.net/sentire2016karanasou.pdf).

Comment: I can have alook at my sample problem from this link https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/4895803001654334/1253884865807279/685654085441754/latest.html

Comment: you can have a look at my sample problem from this link https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/4895803001654334/1253884865807279/685654085441754/latest.html     The results are not so good but you will get an idea. All the training data is encoded with label encoder but we can't encode real time data if we move this model to production. My confusion is real time data comes with characters like gender, artist-id but we can't encode according to our model. Training and testing the model again and again is the only solution to this problem?

Comment: Thank you for the example, it helped me understand a bit. The real time data that will be the input of your production model needs to be transformed in the same way as your train data. E.g. you  can use:  `fit_indexer4 = indexer4.fit(userDF)
 indexed4 = fit_indexer4.transform(userDF).drop('gender')
` the fit_indexer4 that was fit to userDF (that was in turn used to train your regressor) in order to transform every instance of real-time data. (Save and reuse the fit_indexer4)

Comment: If the problem is that your incoming data is in a different form than what your current data is, so that you cannot use the same transformer to make the same transformations, then you should get a sample of the real-time data and adapt to them, so that you end up with a `LabeledPoint(2.0, [282.0,19.0,17.0,4.0,9.0,0.0])` etc. for each instance.

Comment: Unfortunately there is not a single solution to this problem. You have to simulate what your model needs, e.g. get input dato -- > encode_gender --> encode_artist --> parsePoint --> give the result to the already trained regressor to predict.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please also provide any example or link where **linear regression model** has put into production. I wan't to get an Idea how things are done in production enviroment

Comment: I have not found an accessible example with production code yet. For ideas, take a look at [this](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-linear-methods.html#streaming-linear-regression) and [this](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/b22f/33ca65eb26224104f0fc49d41d861eabbf86.pdf) also (If you haven't already).

Answer (score 1):

This data could lend itself quite nicely to [Featuretools](https://www.featuretools.com). It is an open-source automated feature engineering library that explicitly deals with time to make sure you don't introduce label leakage.
For your music data, you could create two `entities`: `"users"` and `"artist_plays"`, and then apply `featuretools.dfs` (Deep Feature Synthesis) to generate features. Think of an entity as being the same as a table in a relational database.  Deep Feature Synthesis creates a single-table feature matrix ready for modeling from multiple different tables complete with high-level statistical features. Here is a [short post](https://www.featurelabs.com/blog/deep-feature-synthesis/) explaining how it works.

This example is using plain Python, but could be adapted for use with Spark or [Dask](https://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/)

```
# Create entityset
import featuretools as ft
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer, StandardScaler
import pandas as pd
import pickle

def load_entityset(user_df, artist_plays_df):
    es = ft.EntitySet("artist plays")
    es.entity_from_dataframe("users", user_df, index="user_id")
    es.entity_from_dataframe("artist_plays", artist_plays_df, index="artist_id")
    es.add_relationship(ft.Relationship(es['users']['user_id'], es['artist_plays']['user_id']))
    return es

user_df = pd.read_csv("training_user.csv")
artist_plays_df = pd.read_csv("training_artist_plays.csv")
es = load_entityset(user_df, artist_plays_df)
feature_matrix, feature_defs = ft.dfs(entityset=es,
                                      target_entity='artist_plays',
                                      ignore_variables={'artist_plays': ['play']})

# encode categoricals
encoded_fm, encoded_fl = ft.encode_features(feature_matrix, feature_defs)

# Impute/scale using SKLearn
imputer = Imputer()
scaler = StandardScaler()

imputed_fm = imputer.fit_transform(encoded_fm)
scaled_fm = scaler.fit_transform(imputed_fm)

# Now, save the encoded feature list, and the imputer/scaler to files to reuse in production
ft.save_features(encoded_fl, 'fl.p')
with open('imputer.p', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(imputer, f)
with open('scaler.p', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(scaler, f)
```

Then in production:

```
import featuretools as ft
import pickle
import pandas as pd

# load previous data
old_user_df = pd.read_csv("training_user.csv")
old_artist_plays_df = pd.read_csv("training_artist_plays.csv")
es_old = load_entityset(old_user_df, old_artist_plays_df)


# load new data
user_df = pd.read_csv("new_user.csv")
artist_plays_df = pd.read_csv("new_artist_plays.csv")
es_updated = load_entityset(user_df, artist_plays_df)

# merge both data sources
es = es_old.concat(es_updated)

# load back in encoded features
features = ft.load_features('fl.p', es)
fm = ft.calculate_feature_matrix(features,
                                 entityset=es,
                                 instance_ids=es_updated['artist_plays'].get_all_instances())

# impute and scale
with open('imputer.p', 'r') as f:
    imputer = pickle.load(f)
imputed_fm = imputer.transform(fm)
with open('scaler.p', 'r') as f:
    scaler = pickle.load(f)
scaled_fm = scaler.transform(imputed_fm)
```

We have a few demos using this workflow, check out [this example](https://github.com/Featuretools/predict_next_purchase) to predict what a grocery shopper will buy in the future.

I have also used this workflow in a real time production environment to do prediction of delivery metrics for large scale software projects- check out this [white paper](https://www.featuretools.com/aipmpaper) we have published that goes through this method and the results in a live deployment in gory detail.